# Passing argument to a Perl class subroutin

Tags: perl

My code is pretty simple. I have a subroutin getModemHost under a package named smconfig.

```
sub getModemHost {
   print 'Modem-'.$_[0].'.Host';
}
```

when Im calling this subroutin with an argument, I see strange values rather than what I passed. The below line prints Modem-smconfig=HASH(0x9433968).Host. I am expecting Modem-1.Host

```
$smconfig->getModemHost(1)
```

Comment: "Class subroutines" are called methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to a method is the invocant, i.e. the object. Use `$_[1]` for the real first argument. Or, more readable:

```
sub getModemHost {
    my ($self, $modem_number) = @_;
    print "Modem-$modem_number.Host";
}
```

See [perlobj](http://p3rl.org/perlobj) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Or something very common:

```
sub myObjectMethod {
    my $self = shift;

    ...

    # do here what you like to do with $_[0]
    # for we have removed the first parameter

    ...

};
```